# use nested table value in where clause(oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, nested-table

i am fairly new to the `Oracle DBMS` and would like to know how to use a member of a nested table in a where clause
**specifically**
i have a nested table named poll_nest

```
   SQL> desc poll_nest
     Name                                      Null?    Type
    ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------

    ID                                                 VARCHAR2(20)
    CID                                                VARCHAR2(20)
```

which was created as follows

```
create or replace type voter_arrive as object(id varchar(20),cid varchar(20));
create or replace type poller as table of voter_arrive;
```

and then it was inserted into the election table as poll_nest

```
    SQL> desc election;
    Name                                      Null?    Type
   ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------

     REGION                                             VARCHAR2(20)
     STIME                                              TIMESTAMP(6)
     ETIME                                              TIMESTAMP(6)
     VOTES                                              POLLER
```

i need to take some actions based on the value of the `cid` attribute of poll_nest that is currently entered(like incrementing a value based on the cid)
so i used an `after trigger` in which i did this:

```
select distinct t.cid into voted from election e,table(e.votes) t where t.cid=:new.votes.cid;
```

but i get a compilation error.
i saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20232794/oracle-trigger-on-nested-table) answer and this too:
[Oracle Nested Table predicate in where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19666943/oracle-nested-table-predicate-in-where-clause)
but couldn't understand how they work..
*could someone please help me with the syntax?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

poll_nest is not a nested table. Its table that stores PL SQL object.

From http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/NESTED_TABLE :

> NESTED TABLE is an Oracle data type used to support columns containing multivalued attributes, in this case, columns that can hold an entire sub-table.

You can insert value in table of object type by first instantiating object constructor like

`insert into poll_nest values (voter_arrive('122','112'));`

For accessing the inserted value you can use

`select e.voter.arrive.cid from poll_tab e where e.voter_arrive.id = '122';`

check out this link too: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/objects.htm

Update: 
I looked up oracle documentation http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/appdev.920/a96624/05_colls.htm , and I found that poller is a nested table. I don't know why they call it nested table, it should be called PL/SQL table only.

I assumed poll_nest to be like, and answered the question
`CREATE TABLE APPS.POLL_NEST
(
  VOTER  APPS.VOTER_ARRIVE
)`

but now I think you have created table and objects like

```
create or replace type voter_arrive as object(id varchar(20),cid varchar(20));


 create or replace type poller as table of voter_arrive;

create  table election(
 REGION                                             VARCHAR2(20),
 STIME                                              TIMESTAMP(6),
 ETIME                                              TIMESTAMP(6),
 VOTES                                              POLLER
)    NESTED TABLE VOTES STORE AS VOTES_TAB;
```

For each region(which should be unique), you are going to save records in VOTES nested table .if I am correct

```
INSERT INTO election
 VALUES ( 'A',
         CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
         CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,poller(voter_arrive('100','001'),voter_arrive('200','002')) )
```

poller() is a constructor of nested table type poller. All values passed to constructor will create new row in poller. So, you can perform insert and update in election table like

```
INSERT INTO table (select e.votes from election e where region ='A')      values((voter_arrive('300','003')))
```

To access individual row in poller nested table you need to use TABLE() function like this: 
    select * from table (select e.votes from election e where region ='A') a where a.id = 100

[image: election table after insert]

Comment: thank u for answering..i tried out the syntax suggested by u and got ORA-04044: procedure, function, package, or type is not allowed here..what could be the error?@crazycloud...i accepted ur answer for making me understand about nested table

Comment: @craycloud thanks for the very informative answer and thanks for ur time!!!good explanation too... :)